# How to mock an imported module with pytest

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

Something similar has been asked before, but I'm struggling to get this to work.

**How do I mock an import module from another file**

I have one file:
`b.py` (named to be consistent with the linked docs)

```
import cv2   # module 'a' in the linked docs

def get_video_frame(path):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)  # `a.SomeClass` in the linked docs
    vidcap.isOpened()
    ...
```

test_b.py

```
import b
import pytest # with pytest-mock installed

def test_get_frame(mocker):

    mock_vidcap = mocker.Mock()
    mock_vidcap.isOpened.side_effect = AssertionError

    mock_cv2 = mocker.patch('cv2.VideoCapture')
    mock_cv2.return_value = mock_vidcap

    b.get_video_frame('foo')    # Doesn't fail

    mock_vidcap.isOpened.assert_called()   # fails
```

I set the tests up like this because in [where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) it specifies that if

> In this case the class we want to patch is being looked up on the a module and so we have to patch a.SomeClass instead:

```
@patch(‘a.SomeClass’)
```

I've tried a few other combinations of patching, but it exhibits the same behavior, which suggests I'm not successfully patching the module. If the patch were to be applied `b.get_video_frame('foo')` would fail due to the `side_effect`; having `assert_called` fail, supports this.

**Edit** in an effort to reduce the length of the question I left off the rest of `get_video_frame`. Unfortunitly, the parts left off we're the critical parts. The full function is:

```
def get_video_frame(path):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)  # `a.SomeClass` in the linked docs
    is_open = vidcap.isOpened()
    while True:
        is_open, frame = vidcap.read()
        if is_open:
            yield frame
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line just creates a generator:

```
b.get_video_frame('foo')
```

The line `is_open = vidcap.isOpened()` is never reached, because in the test function the generator remains frozen at the start, therefore the side effect never raises.

You are otherwise using mocker and patch correctly.